# Upgrading kernel and drivers in a BackTrack ISO

Tags: drivers, system-installation, live-usb

I'm using the latest [BackTrack](http://www.backtrack-linux.org/) ISO release for security analysis. BackTrack is basically a configured Ubuntu distro. However, I'm missing my wireless card driver (Broadcom 4313). There are several forum posts on the site explaining how to upgrade the kernel and install the drivers. However, I use the ISO file from a USB drive as a "Live CD" (i.e., no installation) and can therefore not change the original ISO.

My question is: how can I take an ISO file (any, for this matter), update its contents and repackage it to a new ISO that can be live-mounted? is there a procedure for this? Do I need to use a virtual machine?

Comment: I have two comments for you - I'm not sure if BackTrack would be covered by the Ubuntu umbrella since they seem to have strayed far from it's original base: [Discussion for this can be found on the Meta](http://meta.ubuntu.stackexchange.com/questions/321/should-we-include-support-for-backtrack). Second it appears you have two questions. One regarding this ISO repackaging - the other about Broadcom Drivers. If they are two separate questions please remove one and ask it in a new post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifying an Ubuntu live CD is trickier than just replacing files in the ISO image.

The root filesystem of the live operating system is actually contained within a compressed [SquashFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SquashFS) data file. The modification process typically consists of unpacking the SquashFS file, [chrooting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot) into the extracted filesystem, making your modifications, exiting the chroot, repacking the SquashFS file, and then regenerating the ISO.

This procedure is well described on the [LiveCDCustomization](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization) page of the Ubuntu wiki.

My only experience is with adding packages to the live CD, but there isn't any reason you shouldn't be able to use this to replace the kernel, provided you can compile it successfully.

Comment: Thanks! Frankly, looks like too much work for me :( Guess I'll mount it on a VM and configure it there.

Answer (score 1):

I had used [isomaster](http://www.littlesvr.ca/isomaster/) in the past to add BIOS update programs to a FreeDOS iso. I believe that it is what you want. You can find it in add/remove programs.

[image: screenshot]